# how to use a Rightwards Arrow and Leftwards Arrow flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

How to use a Rightwards Arrow → and Left Arrow ← in calculator I am sharing a code, and please check Also how to use a pi value in the calculator.

```
TableRow(children:[ buildButton("→", 1.8, Color.fromRGBO(1, 88, 155, 1.0)), ]),
```

Comment: why you don't use `Icon` widget

Comment: Is the icon widget work with functionality on textfield?

Comment: This code uses a custom keyboard.